# GWT wrap a html table and add cels

Tags: html, gwt, html-table

I'm using gwt in my web app and I have a html panel which contains a `<table>`. I've chosen to do this instead of flextable due to some annoying issues when styling it as being unable to do `<tbody valign="top">`.

I wanted to know if it's possible to wrap a html table

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Path</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

In a class like Flextable so I can easily control rows and columns through Java?

Something like

```
Label.wrap("id");
```

but for tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also format your data in **FlexTable**.

You can use `flexTable.getRowFormatter()`, `flexTable.getColumnFormatter()` or `flexTable.getColumnFormatter()`.

You can apply alignment, style to rows, columns and cells using above **FlexTable** attributes.

Please provide a standalone test case if you are facing any problems with **FlexTable**.

Comment: in this case that was what I was looking for but let's assume I already had a well formatted and positioned table and I wanted to turn it into a "programmable" table in gwt...can it be done?

Comment: @doubter, What do you mean by programmable? Can you please tell me your requirement?