# GWT wrap a table and manipulate contents programmatically

Tags: html, gwt, html-table

I have a well formatted **HTML table** (the HTML text is generated by a reporting tool) and I want to turn it into a **"programmable" table in GWT**.
I need to show that content as it is provided, but I also need to inspect the DOM, get the tables, and add `ClickHandler`'s to the rows and cells.

I am able to do something similar with images:

```
Html html = new HTML(htmlText);
ImageElement domElement = getChildImageByTagAndId(html.getElement(), "img", "blah");
Image image = Image.wrap(domElement);
image.addClickHandler(...);
```

My question is: What is the correct way to do this with tables?

I could not find a wrap() method for `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` elements.

Note: this question was asked (and not answered) in the comments in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450157/gwt-wrap-a-html-table-and-add-cels).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unaware of an easy way to wrap an existing Table with the sub tr and td elements.

Given the constraint that you are relying on a third party tool, I recommend trying to build a custom table parser which will parse the existing table, build a FlexTable, and then replace the existing table with the new FlexTable.

As ugly as this is, I am not sure there is a better way...

It may depend on how exactly the table is setup, but you may try playing around with something like the below example to go through the existing table and use the getNodeValue() to build the content of the FlexTable....

```
Element table = DOM.getElementById("someTableId");

    int numTopNodes = table.getChildNodes().getLength();

    for(int topNode = 0; topNode < numTopNodes; topNode++){

        Node top = table.getChildNodes().getItem(topNode);
        System.out.println("Top Node: "+top);


        for(int subNode = 0; subNode < top.getChildCount(); subNode ++){

            Node sub = top.getChildNodes().getItem(subNode);
            System.out.println("Sub Node: "+sub);

            for(int rows = 0; rows < sub.getChildCount(); rows ++){

                Node row = sub.getChildNodes().getItem(rows);
                System.out.println("Row: "+row);


                for(int cells = 0; cells < row.getChildCount(); cells++ ){

                    Node cell = row.getChildNodes().getItem(cells);

                    System.out.println("CELL: "+cell.getNodeValue()); // use value to build to build a new FlexTable


                }


            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: Hi Ashton, I did more research and it looks like you are correct: there "right way" to handle it is via a `FlexTable`. This is for when you need fully programmatic access to the table. Anyway for my particular case, I didn't need to do that. I am able to wrap `<tc>` elements with this: `TableCellElement cellElem = ...; HTML cellWidget = HTML.wrap(cellElem); cellWidget.addClickHandler(...);`. As a note: the `wrap()` call works OK in my app, but when I debug I get an exception "A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list". I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: This problem: "A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list" is related to wrapping a child of an already "wrapped" element. You must wrap from the inner most element and work your way back up.